# Не работает Java Script в браузерах IE и FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день! 
Есть код, с помощью которого при клике на кнопку меняется цвет продукта на картинках. В браузерах IE (у меня 11) и FireFox вместо картинок пустое место.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  $(".sovmestimost").css({
    "content": "url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/sovmestimost-" + $(this).val() + ")"
  });
  $(".dvametra").css({
    "content": "url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/dvametra-" + $(this).val() + ")"
  });
  $(".fast-carging").css({
    "content": "url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/fast-carging-" + $(this).val() + ")"
  });
  $(".speed").css({
    "content": "url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/speed-" + $(this).val() + ")"
  });
  $(".sgibania").css({
    "content": "url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/sgibania-" + $(this).val() + ")"
  });

});
```

```css
.sovmestimost {
  width: 100%;
  content: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/sovmestimost-black.jpg);
}

.dvametra {
  width: 100%;
  content: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/dvametra-black.jpg);
}

.fast-carging {
  width: 100%;
  content: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/fast-carging-black.jpg);
}

.speed {
  width: 100%;
  content: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/speed-black.jpg);
}

.sgibania {
  width: 100%;
  content: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/sgibania-black.jpg);
}

.color-usb {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: rgba(98, 192, 221, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 154, 55, 1);
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.color-usb:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(98, 192, 221, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="text-align: center; position: relative;z-index: 99999;">
  <input type="radio" style="display: none;" value="black.jpg" name="radioButton" id="blackButton" />
  <label for="blackButton"><img class="color-usb" src="http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/color-black.png"></label>
  <input type="radio" style="display: none;" value="gray.jpg" name="radioButton" id="grayButton" />
  <label for="grayButton"><img class="color-usb" src="http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/color-gray.png"></label>
</div>

<div class="sovmestimost"></div>
<div class="dvametra"></div>
<div class="fast-carging"></div>
<div class="speed"></div>
<div class="sgibania"></div>
```

Comment: Интересно вы использовали `firebug`? И посмотрели что там не так? Посмотрели консоль? в `FF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css свойство **content** подразумевает использование псевдоселекторов **:before** и **:after**. Содержимое **content** не будет выводится если вы указываете его без одного из псевдоселекторов указанных выше.
Например можно попробовать так:

```
.sovmestimost:after {
  width: 100%;
  content: url(http://di-tech.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/sovmestimost-black.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо! Картинка стала отображаться. А может ещё подскажите, что подправить, что бы она менялась при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: К сожалению _Javascript_ не может работать с псевдоселекторами, так как стили для них нельзя написать в атрибуте **style**. Воспользуйтесь тегом **img** и меняйте атрибут **src**, так можно попробовать _css_ свойство **background** и менять изображение через: `.css('background-image','новый_url')`

Comment: через background-image с width: 100% не получается, пустое место. А если задать фиксированный размер, то теряется резиновость сайта.

Спасибо, Сергей!